# Old electric baseboard heater thermostat wiring

Tags: electrical, thermostat, electric-heat

I have a question about an old federal pacific baseboard heater thermostat's wiring. 
I disconnected this thermostat 2 weeks ago, thinking that we were going to remove the heater. Now we've decided to keep the heater, and I don't remember how the thermostat was wired. 
The therm box has two lines in it: one in, one out. Each line has 1 black, one white, and one bare ground. 
I have attached a pic of the back of the thermostat. It only has 3 places to connect. Poles 2, 3, and 4. 
Can anyone help me out and tell me what hooks to each pole?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wait, terminal 1 is missing? Is this a 120V heater, not 240V?

Comment: I would agree on not connecting backwards, but one of the line terminals looks unused. It was common to only break 1 side of a 240v heater in years past. Then one of the lines would directly connect to one of the loads., tried posting this to your answer but it would not let me

Comment: All 3 terminals appear to have been hooked up. I can see a small scratch or indent under each screw.

Comment: I just added another pic.   There are 2 heaters on this line. Each have their own thermostat. This is a very crude diagram of the first heater's thermostat wiring.

Comment: Maybe that will help give an idea of what the guy was doing when he installed these?

Comment: The 2 whites and 1 black that form an arrow top-center are capped together.

Comment: So, let me ask this.  If this is rewired by only breaking one side of the 240v, would I hook one black to #3, the other black to #4, and the whites capped together? Then the bare ground from both sides to the ground screw on the back of the therm?

Comment: This is 240V, and the 2 wires are interchangeable, so pretend the white wires are just more black wires.  In fact, they should have been marked black.

Answer (score 1):

This is 240V split-phase, so both hots are equivalent.  The white wire should be remarked one of the 8 legal hot colors, since it is not a neutral.  If I were wiring this in conduit, with the choice of any of 8 colors, I would use black and black because the hots are interchangeable; no need to distinguish hots from each other.

This thermostat is single pole.  They make a double-pole version where terminal 1 is populated, that one connects 1-3 and also 2-4.  This one simply leaves in terminal 3 as a convenient splice block, it connects to no other terminal ever.

Pick one wire from each cable; join them (I don't care how as long as it's code legal; feel free to use terminal 3 as a splice block).

Of the two remaining wires, put one on each of the terminals 1 and 3.